# Exoplayer keeps playing the audio even when video is stopped after

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer

I am using exoplayer and I noticed when I play a video in one activity and then switch to another by pressing on a button the video itself stops playing in order to switch to the new activity, but the audio keeps playing. If I return to the old activity and play the video again the audio is still going + I hear the audio from playing the video again and hear the audio two times now simulteanously at different times of the song.

```
String url = model.getVideo();
            try {
                BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter= new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
                TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory( bandwidthMeter));
                holder.exoPlayer= ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance( LiFit.getContext(),trackSelector );
                Uri videouri = Uri.parse(model.getVideo());
                DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
                ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory= new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
                MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videouri,dataSourceFactory,extractorsFactory,null,null);
                holder.videoView.setPlayer(holder.exoPlayer);
                holder.exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
                //holder.exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Nichts
            }
```

This is the code I am using does somebody know a solution for this problem ?

Comment: Where are you stopping the previous video in your code?

Comment: Never lol when should I stop it ? Is there some kind of Listener for it ?

Comment: This will really help you click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499013/stop-and-release-exoplayer-from-viewpager-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exoplayer has a method [setPlayWhenReady](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.html#setPlayWhenReady-boolean-) which can be used to play/pause the media, and a [release](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.html#release--) method when the player is no longer needed.

You can use these methods when switching to another activity.